# How to compare date time in range with hour

Tags: c#

I want know another day between in the range like:

26-12-2017 5:45pm.Is this in range of 6pm Monday and 6pm Wednesday.

please help me to solve it.i just can know the day,but how to solve hour

Comment: Can any body tell me im wrong some thing in my question???

Comment: You didnt show what you have tried, you only asked for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication59
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(("26-12-2017 5:45pm").ToUpper(),"dd-MM-yyyy h:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            int dayOfWeek = (int)time.DayOfWeek;
            DateTime saturdaySundayMidnight = time.AddDays(-dayOfWeek).Date;
            TimeSpan timeOfWeek = time.Subtract(saturdaySundayMidnight);
            TimeSpan  startTime = new TimeSpan(1,17,45,0);  //Monday 5:45PM
            TimeSpan  endTime = new TimeSpan(3,18,0,0);  //Wednesday 6:00PM

            if ((timeOfWeek >= startTime) && (timeOfWeek <= endTime))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("In Range");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above has issues when switching between DayLight Saving Time and Standard time which occurs Sunday Morning.  So using Sunday/Monday midnight is better.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication59
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(("26-12-2017 5:45pm").ToUpper(),"dd-MM-yyyy h:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            int dayOfWeek = ((int)time.DayOfWeek - 1) % 7; //Monday day 0 instead of sunday
            DateTime sundayMondayMidnight = time.AddDays(-dayOfWeek).Date;
            TimeSpan timeOfWeek = time.Subtract(sundayMondayMidnight);
            TimeSpan  startTime = new TimeSpan(0,17,45,0);  //Monday 5:45PM
            TimeSpan  endTime = new TimeSpan(2,18,0,0);  //Wednesday 6:00PM

            if ((timeOfWeek >= startTime) && (timeOfWeek <= endTime))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("In Range");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @jdweng because i dont know about Timespan to get the the time of first day and third day.thanks again jdweng

Comment: new TimeSpan(days, hours, minutes, seconds).  StartTime I guess should be (0,18,0,0) not (0,17,45,0).